# Unable to launch pyspark in Windows 10

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

I am unable to start pyspark in Windows 10 PC. I followed all steps given in link "https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/apache-spark-installation-on-windows/"

I have installed Python 3.9, Java 8 and have set their path in environment variables : -

[image]

Then I have set SPARK_HOME and HADOOP_HOME system variables as below : -

[image]

[image]

But still unable to start pyspark in cmd as below : -

[image]

Can anybody let me know how to fix this issue "**Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @4961f6a**f"

This seems to be the root cause of this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop comes pre-installed in hortonworks VM.

1. Install Oracle virtualbox
2. Run hortonworks sandbox in it